# How to find the Flixbus timetable for a specific route?

Tags: online-resources, buses, flixbus, timetables

Is there any way to see the timetable for a [Flixbus](https://flixbus.com) bus route?

On their website I can see the routes map, but I'd me more interested in seeing where the bus is going to stop for a given route.

E.g. if a bus goes from `Rotterdam` to `Amsterdam`, I'd like to see each stop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Flixbus app for the iPhone you can see the stops, for a bought ticket.

Alternatively, you can search the *connection* printed on the ticket (`<number> <final_destination>`) and you will find the timetables on some website which lists the timetables of multiple companies.

---

**What Flixbus Support said** (original answer)

I've just talked to someone from Flixbus support and they don't have this data in a public format.

Only they can see it and one who wants to know the timetable, can ask them on the phone.

Using [the route map](https://www.flixbus.com/bus-routes) one can see the direct connections between the cities, so assuming there is a direct connection between `A` and `D` there will be direct connections between `A` and `B` and `B` and `C` and `C` and `D`, but those will be guessed—as the person from Flixbus said: *You can play with that map*.

Answer (score 4):

It is annoying and cumbersome that there isn't a way to access this data directly. However, I found a workaround that works well enough in most situations:

On the flixbus homepage, head to the "[Current Route Information](https://global.flixbus.com/info)" (currently under menu point "Service"). There you can either type in your departure stop and time or your destination and arrival time. You can then find your bus line under the departure or arrivals tab, respectively. If you click on either of the stops, the intermediate stops and their times will show up.

**Please note though that this works only if a bus on your line leaves in the next 24 hrs!** That means that you might not be able to check for a bus that only leaves on the weekend during a weekday and viceversa. Also, you should check departure and arrival times very well to see if the bus might take a different route than at the date you are planning to travel.